# How to host / point asp.net website as umbraco sub site

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, umbraco, umbraco6, umbraco7

I have two website one is umbraco site and other one is asp.net site both on different location on same server

1)   Umbraco site ( umbraco V6 and IIS 7)  And bind on let say Eg.  `http://localhost:8090/`

2)  Asp.net website. (Simple Asp.net Site)

Now I have added Asp.net website as Application in umbraco web site IIS and given Alias let say AspSubSite

My  umbraco site is running fine. But when I try to access asp.net site by URL `http://localhost:8090/AspSubSite`

It is not working.

I have try adding respective Url to umbraco config key “umbracoReservedUrls” but that also didn’t work

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the folders to exclude (/aspSubSite) in the web.config of the umbraco installation.
Umbraco will not interfere at all with this folders.  To do this, add the folder to the umbracoReservedPaths in the appSettings section of the web.config.

```
<add key="umbracoReservedPaths" value="/umbraco,/install/,/aspSubSite/" />
```

(leave the existing paths, but just add your path at the end.)

Note: this will exclude ALL umbraco functionality from this folder.  Including rendering partial's, macro's, ...  Only do this if you really want to do this.  If you want to use e.g. a common menu, this won't work anymore.